# looping lists in java

Tags: java

I have a simple java statement along the lines of:

```
    String[] ykl = yklList.get(0).split(" ");
```

where, yklList is an ArrayList containing sentences which are split into words. The above works fine.

When I now try and loop this:

```
Loop:1
for (int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
  String[] ykl = yklList.get(i).split(" ");
}
```

It does not seem to work and throws me a compile error. Is the above loop wrong?

I have another for loop after the above:

```
Loop:2
for (String ykl : yklList)
{
//do something
}
```

It throws me a compile error here saying:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ykl
location: class test
for (String ykl : yklList)
```

Presumably Loop 1 went wrong somewhere?

**Edit:**

The "full" code looks something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<=yklList.size()-1;i++)
{
String[] ykl = yklList.get(i).split(" ");  

}       
for (String y : ykl)  
{  
t.add(y);  
}
```

and the error is:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ykl
location: class test
for (String y : ykl)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know *which* compile error you get...

Comment: *What* compile error is thrown?

Comment: do you have 5+ elements in yklList?

Comment: pls add the whole code segment. the error says yklList is known in the first but not in the second loop. no way of telling why without seeing all the code in-between

Comment: I hope 'Loop: 1' and 'Loop:2' aren't in your actual code....

Comment: Amir: no, those words are not in the actual code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding to your update:

You define `ykl` in the first loop. So the variable is not in the scope of the second loop. Your code have to look like this:

```
for (String yklSentence : yklList) {
   String[] ykl = yklSentence.split(" ");  
   for (String y : ykl) {  
     t.add(y);  
   } 
}
```

By the way: If you would use an IDE like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) you would see those errors in the editor!

Comment: Hi there.. your solution has seemed to solve the problem. But, I do not understand why. A variable declared in a loop, should be available to another loop I would have thought? Is that wrong? Is this something specific to Java? Thanks again for your solution

Comment: Yes, that's wrong and it's not specific to Java. If a variable is defined within a block (within curly brackets) it is only visible in this block (and blocks within this block).

Answer (score 1):

In your appendix, the second cycle does not know about the variable ykl, as defined in the previous cycle and after leaving it - it is destroyed.

If variables were not removed - after a while all of the available computer memory would be filled, which would cause an error of the program. If only you were given the opportunity dal unnecessary variables - that is allowed a situation where you forgot to remove unneeded variables and memory, again, would be full. In this context, Java simplifies the development and can not think about what you are then permennye not removed.

To correct the error:

```
ArrayList <String> yklList = new ArrayList <String> ();
ArrayList <String> t = new ArrayList <String> ();

for (int i = 0; i <yklList.size (); i + +)
         {
             String [] ykl = yklList.get (i). Split ("");
             for (String y: ykl)
                 t.add (y);
         }
```

or:
If you fill out absolutely all characters t of yklList:

```
ArrayList<String> yklList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] ykl = new String[0];

        for (int i=0;i<yklList.size();i++) {
            String[] tempYkl = yklList.get(i).split(" ");
            String[] tempYklDub = new String[tempYkl.length];
            String[] tempYklDubDub = new String[ykl.length];
            for (int z=0; z< tempYkl.length; z++)
                tempYklDub[z] = tempYkl[z];
            for (int z=0; z<ykl.length; z++)
                tempYklDubDub[z]=ykl[z];
            ykl = new String[tempYklDubDub.length+tempYklDub.length];
            for (int z=0; z<tempYklDubDub.length; z++)
                ykl[z]=tempYklDubDub[z];
            for (int z=tempYklDubDub.length, k=0; k<tempYklDub.length; z++, k++)
                ykl[z]=tempYklDub[k];
        }
        for (String y : ykl)
            t.add(y);
```

Comment: thank a lot torch for your explanation. So basically Java has an automatic garbage collector is what I understand from your comment. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure looping the right count of elements.

Try using [size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) for your ArrayList:

```
for (int i=0;i<ykl.size();i++)
{
  String[] ykl = yklList.get(i).split(" ");
}
```

Keep in mind that every cycle overwrites your `ykl` array. Defining it outside of your loop would solve this problem.

**Edit:**
Try

```
String[] ykl = new String[ykl.size()];
for (int i=0;i<ykl.size();i++)
{
  ykl[i] = yklList.get(i).split(" ");
}

for (String y : ykl)  
{  
t.add(y);  
}
```

Comment: Fuzzy, I completely agree with what you say. Since I was getting the compile error, I manually changed it to a number to loop on, to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @JamesW: Variables are local to { } blocks unless declared otherwise. Keep this in mind when declaring arrays inside a loop and using them outside ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have less than 4 yklList elements.
And, at the next iteration, it tries to take an element from outside the yklList

Solutions to the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i <yklList.size(); i + +) {
    String[] ykl = yklList.get(i).split(" ");
}
```

or

```
for (String yklListDub: yklList) {
    String[] ykl = yklListDub.split(" ");
}
```

P.S. I'm sorry for my english)